# Object: true error: did not understand #value while anding booleans together

Tags: gnu-smalltalk

I'm attempting to solve AoC problem 12 part 2 in Smalltalk. The specific aren't super relevant, but here's the relevant portion of a single-dimensional version of the model I'm using for the problem:

```
Object subclass: Moon [
    | X XX Xin |
    init [
        X := 0. XX := 0. Xin := 0.
    ]
    Moon class >> new [ | moon | moon := super new. moon init. ^moon]
    x: xx [ 
        X := xx. XX := 0. Xin := xx.
    ]
    kinetic [ ^ (XX abs) ]
    initialState [ | killmeNow |
        killmeNow := ((self kinetic) == 0).
        killmeNow := killmeNow and: (Xin == X).
        ^killmeNow
    ]
]

moonA := Moon new.
moonA x:  1.
moonA initialState printNl.
```

As the variable names just might suggest, I'm failing at the highly complex task of checking if a number equals zero *and* a second number equals a third number. No amount of refactoring of this statement seems to change the ultimate outcome:

```
Object: true error: did not understand #value
MessageNotUnderstood(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
True(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #value (SysExcept.st:1448)
True>>and: (True.st:116)
Moon>>initialState (omg.st:15)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (omg.st:22)
```

What is the `#Value` that `(self kin == 0)` is receiving, why is it not `True`, and how do I fix this?

Comment: I'm asking on stack overflow how to and two booleans together. This might just be the lowest point of my career

Comment: No, inlining `kinetic` to say `killmeNow := (XX == 0).` doesn't change things.

Comment: it should be noted that `(self kin == 0) and: (X == Xin) inspect.` does tell me I'm dealing with a `True`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of the `and:` message must be a `Block` (and you are passing a `Boolean`). Just change your code like this

```
 killmeNow := killmeNow and: [Xin == X].   "squared brackets rather that parentheses"
```

You could also have written the same more succinctly as

```
  initialState [
     ^self kinetic = 0 and: [Xin = X]
    ]
```

but, of course, this is secondary. Note that I've used `=` instead of `==` because both have a slightly different semantics and you don't need object identity in these tests (even though `==` will work as well in your case).

---

For the sake of completeness, let me mention that there is way to *and* Booleans: the binary message `&` does that. So, you could have written

```
    ^(self kinetic = 0) & (Xin = X).
```

The precedence rules of the Smalltalk syntax allow you to remove the parentheses around `self kinetic = 0` because here the main message is `=` which is also binary. The parantheses aroung `Xin = X` cannot be removed, otherwise `&` would take precedence over the last occurrence of `=`.

Comment: Yeah, my original writing of the condition was terser, then I started desperately adding parentheses to try and get the thing to work...